# Check if a file path matches any of the patterns in a blacklist

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file-system

I'm processing a list of files, and want to check the filenames against a list of regex, like:

```
IGNORE_FILES = [
    re.compile('^./Vendor.*'),
    re.compile('^./Pods.*'), 
    …
]

def in_blacklist(file):
    return len(list(filter(lambda r: r.match(file) != None, IGNORE_FILES))) > 0

def in_whitelist(file):
    return SWIFT_FILE_REGEX.match(file) != None

def files():
    valid_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for file in files:
            if in_whitelist(file) and not in_blacklist(root):
                valid_files.append("%s/%s" % (root, file))
    return valid_files
```

I'm looking for a smoother way to write:

```
len(list(filter(lambda r: r.match(root) != None, IGNORE_FILES))) == 0
```

I feel that it's not so easy to read, and especially with the `list(..)`

Comment: Are there any reasons you're not using string comparisons ?

Comment: You mean as opposed to regex?

Comment: A "smoother way to write" as in, writing it into a well-named function and calling that instead? I hope so... that one-liner is pretty dreadful!

Comment: @Phrancis Putting 'return len(list(filter(lambda r: r.match(root) != None, IGNORE_FILES))) == 0' into a function doesn't make much of a difference, surley, the initial code-snippet will look better, but my question was specifically about that part of the line

Comment: @Phrancis I can update the question with your comment, but still the question applies to the contents of 'in_blacklist'

Comment: @Phrancis see updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build one regex out of the list of regexes by

```
'|'.join(IGNORE_FILES)
```

(Well, before running `re.compile` on them...)

Then your `in_blacklist` function becomes as easy to write and read as `in_whitelist`.

I further assume that you don't want to ignore paths that start with any letter, but those starting with a literal dot (which is what `os.walk('.')` yields). So you need to escape those leading dots.

Also, in your `files()` function, you should move your `in_blacklist` check out of the inner loop. No need to check the same root directory multiple times.

So:

```
IGNORE_FILES = re.compile('|'.join([
    r'^\./Vendor.*',
    r'^\./Pods.*', 
]))

def in_blacklist(file):
    return IGNORE_FILES.match(file) != None

def in_whitelist(file):
    return SWIFT_FILE_REGEX.match(file) != None

def files():
    valid_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        if in_blacklist(root):
            continue
        for file in files:
            if in_whitelist(file):
                valid_files.append("%s/%s" % (root, file))
    return valid_files
```

And for more portability, you could replace `"%s/%s" % (root, file)` by `os.path.join(root, file)`, but I wouldn't insist on this too hard...

Comment: That's a good idea. I will go with that change :) Though I wonder if t might impact the regex in any way? I mean to limit the possibilities with the regexp, (for example groups would be strange with this, though Im fine with it since I dont plan to use groups here..)

Comment: It makes the regex more computationally expensive,  but should not change semantics. And as long as all your regexes start with '^', the regex engine can detect a non-match early on and move on to the next one. I'm not sure whether there might be some worst-case scenarios for the regex engine where its computation time exceeds the time you need for individual checks, but if so, they should be rare.

Answer (score 4):

I find your use of "blacklist" and "whitelist" problematic.

What is a "whitelist"? Which takes precedence — a whitelist or a blacklist? (Adding an e-mail address to a whitelist should let it bypass a spam filter.)

As @JoeWallis has already pointed out, if the directory is in the blacklist, then there is no need to iterate through its contents. To add to the confusion, the blacklist works on directories, but the whitelist works on filenames. It would be clearer to name them `exclude_dirs` and `filename_filter`. If, as I suspect, you are using the filename filter to look for a `.swift` extension, consider using [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) as a more natural alternative to a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a comprehension.
Comprehensions are like easier to write `map`s and `filter`s.
Your in_blacklist can actually be a generator comprehension.
One that `yield`s rather than `array.append`s.
Wrapped in an `any`.
This is if there is at least one match it's True.
And you don't really want to check the rest.

You can also change your `files` function to use one, all you need to do is move the [discouraged printf string format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) to the beginning and keep the rest the same.
You can also move `if not in_blacklist(root)` up so that if the root is not allowed then you're not spending time on the children.

```
IGNORE_FILES = [
    re.compile('^./Vendor.*'),
    re.compile('^./Pods.*'), 
    …
]

def in_blacklist(string):
    return any(r.match(string) is not None for r in IGNORE_FILES)

def in_whitelist(file):
    return SWIFT_FILE_REGEX.match(file) is not None

def files():
    return [
        '{}/{}'.format(root, file)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.')
        if not in_blacklist(root)
        for file_name in files
        if in_whitelist(file_name)
    ]
```

Comment: Hmm, I actually tried with a list comprehension, but didn't get it correctly.  In `in_blacklist` you dont need `[` and `]` for the list comprehension?

Comment: @netigger As I said it's not a list comprehension, it's a generator comprehension. Which allows you to remove the `()` if it's the sole argument to a function as `any((i for i in range(10)))` would look ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

#### Type hints

Since you are using Python 3.x you could take advantage of the new [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html). According to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/):

> This PEP aims to provide a standard syntax for type annotations, opening up Python code to easier static analysis and refactoring, potential runtime type checking, and (perhaps, in some contexts) code generation utilizing type information.
>
> Of these goals, static analysis is the most important. This includes support for off-line type checkers such as mypy, as well as providing a standard notation that can be used by IDEs for code completion and refactoring.

Even if you don't use static code analysis at the moment, type hints still have the advantage of making the code easier to read and understand.

---

In your case, adding type hints (along with adding a verb like `is_something` instead of `something`) to functions would make the code more clear. Since this is about file names, I'd also suggest using `file_name` instead of `file`, so it's clear we're dealing with a string and not an actual file. For example:

```
def is_in_whitelist(file_name: str) -> bool:
    return SWIFT_FILE_REGEX.match(file_name) != None
```

---

In the same vein, `IGNORE_FILES` may be better named as `IGNORED_ROOT_NAMES` since that is what they actually are. [pixelbrei's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144736/42632) addressed a great way to simplify it.

Comment: Great hints as well. Though Atom certainly freaks out when I add '-> bool'. It will lose the syntax coloring for the next function.

Comment: Strange, maybe Atom has some fix for it... I've used that syntax in IDLE as well as a few online REPL with no problems...